# Best Photoshop-Wordpress workflow for editing images without re-upload

Tags: images, uploads, plugin-recommendation, workflow

When I have images uploaded to Wordpress, there is no way for me to flexibly edit these images. For example, let's say I want to add a colored overlay over an image that has been uploaded to Wordpress. For me to do this, I have to add the overlay to the image, then upload the new modified image to Wordpress. When I am developing a non-Wordpress site, however, all I have to do is link to the photo in the CSS, then using the Image Assets generator, the linked image is changed on the fly. This saves me from having to re-upload photos every time I make a change.

Is there any Photoshop script or plugin, or just a method in general for editing photos without having to re-upload them to Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Why do people use CMS? they use it to avoid having to handle HTML structure, JS and CSS on a page by page base and focus on the content. But if you do want to handle them that way because it save you time, then maybe wordpress is not the best solution for you.

Wordpress has to know what is the content of the pages to be able to function properly and image are part of the content (therefor having them in CSS is a no no), and you have to tell wordpress that it has an image at someway, with the most obvious one is to upload it via the upload windows. If you just ftp the image as PS probably does wordpress will not know about it.

Why is it important for wordpress to know about images? Because then the author can select them from the media library without reuploading them, automatic tools can generate thumbnail to be displayed at various place on the site and the image can be mark as a "feature image" to facebook or other 3rd parties.

The workflow with images in wordpress is to photoshop them before uploading the initial content.